# Unable to access _POST values PHP

Tags: php

Find below my form and the action page it submits to. The _POST array is empty. Not sure how. Please help.

### index.php

```
<form method="post" action="track-them.php">
<input type="text" width="255" id="txt" />
<textarea id="ta" type="text" cols="25" rows="4"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="check-button" value="Ok" />
</form>
```

### track-them.php

```
<?php
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Both fields txt & ta have values but the output I see when I click submit is:

Array ( )

Comment: Do you strip slashes for magic quote GPC?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `name` attribute to your form elements:

```
<form method="post" action="track-them.php">
<input type="txt" width="255" id="myurl" name="myurl" />
<textarea id="ta" name="ta" type="text" cols="25" rows="4"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="check-button" value="Ok" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Give your inputs a name.  The browser passes the name attribute not the id.

Comment: Actually, that answer is not completely correct - it's not PHP using that value but the browser. PHP just uses whatever is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the print_r($_POST) above the inclution what is the result ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add `name` attribute for each from element